# Print PDF documents in folder, but specific pages

Tags: windows, pdf

I want to print multiple PDF documents in a folder, but only specific pages (but the same range for all, or better **not** print specific pages). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Open them all and print each page. How many documents are we talking about? In the range of 10 or 50,000?

Comment: 20-40, yeah but I need to specify all pages that I wanna print again and again. Thought there would be an easier way, like a .bat file or something.

Comment: Seems you could print all the pages rather easily. http://smallbusiness.chron.com/print-multiple-pdf-files-opening-one-56690.html I know that is wasteful since you only want certain pages, but better than one by one. Also if you have Acrobat look here https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1138309 One other option is any programming language that has a PDF addin, creating something yourself

Comment: The option with the scripts would be nice, seems like its only available in the Pro version of Acrobat Reader? The programming thing, I could do a little C++, Java thingy that is for sure.

Comment: I have done similar things in VB .NET. Look into adding the adobe reader into C++. I am sure it can't be that difficult as the VB .NET addin is incredibly easy. Then you just call up some open / print page methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are free third-party tools for viewing and printing PDF files, such as [Sumatra](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) and [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) , that have command-line arguments to specify which documents(s) and page(s) to print ([for Sumatra](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments.html)  and [for PDF-XChange Viewer](http://help.tracker-software.com/EUM/default.aspx?pageid=PDFXView25:command_line_options)).

E.G., for Sumatra:

`-print-settings "1-3,5,"` prints pages 1,2,3, 5 & 9.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!